# SteamOS on Android via Termux, VNC and Qemu

Tags: android, qemu, termux, vnc-server, samsung

Could someone help me setting up adding the steam deck recovery image via the Qemu system on my android phone via Termux

I am using the link below and the command below.

But I need some help setting up the virtual hard disk and getting the image to to work.

I am trying to get some more of my CPU cores to go to speed the process up.

I was thinking about loading the IMG on to say VMware creating the OS itself onto a VMDK file and then just use that to boot the VM.

But anyhow any advice, would be really really awesome.

I downloaded the ISO from

https://www.mediafire.com/file/5cve5uvz75ylgyf/SteamOS_ISO_File_by_Techrechard.com.iso/file

Qemu emulator termux commands

Created the disk

qemu-img create -f vmdk ./home/storage/downloads/steamOS/steamOSx.vmdk 64G

Launched the image as a VNC with 4GB ram and the ISO with EFI Bios boot

qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu qemu64 -m 4096 -vnc 127.0.0.1:2 -hdd ./home/storage/downloads/steamOS/steamOSx.vmdk -bios ./usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd

Reference:

https://blogs.igalia.com/berto/2022/07/05/running-the-steam-decks-os-in-a-virtual-machine-using-qemu/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Winulator or Box86 in Termux. I have found in personal experience that QEMU is very slow to load, slow after loading, and very memory hungry.